# Jquery Tablesorter plugin not working

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery tablesorter plugin in my application to sort the list.
I am using jquery for validation and popups also. When I use jquery tablesorter, I am not able to sort  and some of the other jquery functions does not work.

I am getting an error `$("myTable").tablesorter() is not a function`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This means that the plugin is not loaded correctly.

Comment: include `jquery.js` before `tablesorter.js`

Comment: Also, make sure you are only loading one copy of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

that may be conflict issue
use noconflict method

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/